# How do I get the path of the last listed directory in a directory?

Tags: python, directory

I have a folder setup that looks like this.

```
myscript.py
directory/
- subdir1/
- subdir2/
- subdir3/
```

Sometimes new folders get added to `directory/`, But each new folder is always named `subdirX`, where X is a number that increments by one.

How do I get the path of the last folder to be listed in `directory/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `os.listdir()` to get all the files in the directories, then use `max()` get the file with the highest suffix number, and finally use `os.path.join()` to join the file name with the directory name for a full path name.

```
import os
print(os.path.join('directory', max(os.listdir('directory'), key=lambda n: int(n.replace('subdir', '')))))
```

Comment: Needlessly removes and then re-adds the subdir string.

Comment: Please read again. The removal is only done inside the key function for numeric comparisons. There's never any "re-adding" afterwards. The only thing that is done afterwards is joining with the main directory and has nothing to do with the subdirectory.

Comment: you are so right

Answer (score 1):

```
x = ['subdir{}'.format(i) for i in range(100)]
max(x, key=lambda n: int(n[6:]))
```

The max function will sort lexicographically, but that will place '99' after '100' (9 > 1). So first extract the integer part (n[6:]), convert to an int, and get the max from there.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is check the last created file. You can do this checking the status of the folder by the command `os.stat(folder).st_ctime`:

```
import os
last =  max(os.listdir(), key=lambda x: os.stat(x).st_ctime)
```